# Python regex insert

Tags: python, regex

I have a String s

```
s = "x01777"
```

Now I want to insert a `-` into s at this position:

```
s = "x01-777"
```

I tried to do this with `re.sub()` but I can't figure out how to insert the `-` without deleting my regex (I need this complex structure of regex because the String I want to work with is much longer).

Actually, it looks something like this:

```
re.sub('\w\d\d\d\d\d', 'here comes my replacement', s)
```

How do I have to set up my insertion?

Comment: is the `-` always after the 3rd char? Why use a regext for that. A couple string operations would be far simpler.

Comment: I was told to use a regex. The string format could change, but there would always be this pattern somewhere inside the string

Comment: What pattern? Please provide some more examples.

Comment: So, the string you are replacing this in could actually be much longer and contain several such numbers?

Comment: @LutzHorn this pattern: '\w\d\d\d\d\d'

Comment: @tobias_k it could be much longer. and no, this pattern will only occur once

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Capture the first three characters into a  group and then the next three to another group. In the replacement part just add `-` after the first captured group followed by the second captured group.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "x01777"
>>> m = re.sub(r'(\w\d\d)(\d\d\d)', r'\1-\2', s)
>>> m
'x01-777'
>>>
```

Comment: Using `(.*)` isn't a good idea. You should match 3 digits instead.

Comment: this is the solution! thank you very much! Will accept your answer asap

Comment: Note that you must include the `r` before the `repl` string otherwise you may get escape characters in your output.

Example:
`re.sub("(\w)(\n)", "\1.\2", "This is a test\nFollowed by second test.")` --> `"'This is a tes\x01.\x02Followed by second test.'"`